# Focus in the input tag goes away after updating it's value through class method in angular(8.x)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, input, angular8

I am Implementing a credit card payment and I am formatting its no through some methods as follows:

> HTML

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let formField of cardFields;let cardFieldIndex = index;">
            <label class="form-label">{{formField.label}}</label>
            <input class="form-input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="formField.val" [placeholder]="formField.label" (ngModelChange)="changeCardField(cardFieldIndex, $event)">
          </div>
```

> app.payment.component.ts

```
changeCardField(index, ev) {
    const formatFields = ({key}, val) => {
      if (key === 'card_number') {
        val = val.split(/[^0-9]/).join('');
        return getCardType(val);
      } 
      return val.trim();
    };
    this.cardFields[index] = {...this.cardFields[index], ...formatFields(this.cardFields[index], this.cardFields[index].val)};
  }
```

I tried it in multiple ways

1. Using de-bounce with setTimeout
2. Using $event.target.focus()
3. straight forward updating field with combination of `[value]="formField.val"` and `(keyup/change/ngModelChange)="changeCardField(cardFieldIndex, $event)"`

In all cases focus of input element goes away. Not able to find a way to get out of it.

Which leads that I am not able to type in input field properly

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this (Not a perfect solution):

> HTML

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let formField of cardFields;let cardFieldIndex = index;">
            <label class="form-label">{{formField.label}}</label>
            <input class="form-input" type="text" #CardNumberInput [(ngModel)]="formField.val" [placeholder]="formField.label" (keydown)="changeCardField(cardFieldIndex, $event)">
          </div>
```

added view variable CardNumberInput

> app.payment.component.ts

```
import {ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';

let commitTimer;
export class AppPaymentComponent {
...

    @ViewChildren("CardNumberInput") cardNumberInput: QueryList<ElementRef>;

...

    changeCardField(index, ev) {
        clearTimeout(commitTimer);
        const formatFields = ({key}, val) => {
            if (key === 'card_number') {
                val = val.split(/[^0-9]/).join('');
                return getCardType(val);
            } else if (key === 'expiry_date') {
                val = val.split(/[^0-9/]/).join('');
                if (val.length === 2) {
                    val += '/';
                } else {
                    val = val.substring(0, 6);
                }
            } else if (key === 'security_number') {
                val = val.split(/[^0-9]/).join('');
                val = val.substring(0, 4);
            }
            return val.trim();
        };
       commitTimer = setTimeout(() => {
         this.cardFields[ind] = {...cardFields, ...formatFields(cardFields, cardFields.val)};
            setTimeout(() => {
              const currentElm = this.cardNumberInput.toArray()[ind].nativeElement;
              currentElm.focus(); // will focus current input field
              currentElm.selectionStart = currentElm.selectionEnd = 10000; // will move cursor to end of input field
            }, 0);
          }, 500);

    }

    ...
}
```

> Main changes: In your workaround you were working through $event.target which goes away after render I used viewChild
>   Focus input after rerender and move cursor to it's end

Let me know in both case, if it works or doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working. But it focuses input after fraction of seconds of re-render.